# Horizontal scrolling page with scroll snap?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a basic skeleton for a horizontal scrolling page that uses any working jQuery plugin to have each section snap to the viewport.

My current fiddle is located [here](http://jsfiddle.net/blackvibes/BxCy8/). Please check it out.

For the scroll snap I'm using [jQuery scrollsnap](https://github.com/benoitpointet/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin) which also uses ScrollStop. On the demo page of Scrollsnap, you see a horizontal scrolling example, working. However, mine is pretty much the same, but not working..

Who knows how to fix this horizontal scrolling issue including snap to each edge?

Thanks!

**Basic HTML skeleton**

```
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        ...
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        ...
      </div>
    </section>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

Accomponied with CSS

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#wrap {
  height:100%;
  width:500%; // 100% for each section
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:scroll;
}

section {
  width:20%; 100% / count of section
  height:100%;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add **direction: x** for horizontal snapping, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scrollsnap({
        direction: 'x',
        snaps: 'snap',
        proximity: 12
    });
});
```

Comment: For anyone that finds this, this library is now located here: https://github.com/benoitpointet/jquery-scrollsnap-plugin